# How to change and format date with C

Tags: c, date, datetime

I want to increase date using days... For example if todays is 27.05.2015 and I add 6 days it should print 3.06.2015

Here is my try:

```
   time_t now;
    struct tm *tm;

    now = time(0);
    if ((tm = localtime (&now)) == NULL) {
        printf ("Error extracting time stuff\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("%02d-%02d-%04d\n", tm->tm_mday + 6, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_year+1900);
```

This will outpyt:

> 33-05-2015

Also How I can format date like this:

> 27-JUN-2015

Comment: Convert it to seconds, and add the `6 * 24 * 3600` to the value, then go back to `struct tm*`.

Comment: Have you seen a calendar - months do change.

Comment: How to add it to value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this you can

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(void)
 {
    struct timeval tv;
    char           str[12];
    struct tm     *tm;

    if (gettimeofday(&tv, NULL) == -1)
        return -1; /* error occurred */
    if ((tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec)) != NULL)
     {
        /* Format as you want */
        strftime(str, sizeof(str), "%d-%b-%Y", tm);
        printf("Today                  : %s\n", str);
     }

    tv.tv_sec += 6 * 24 * 3600; /* add 6 days converted to seconds */
    if ((tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec)) != NULL)
     {
        /* Format as you want */
        strftime(str, sizeof(str), "%d-%b-%Y", tm);
        printf("After 6 days from today: %s\n", str);
     }

    return 0;
 }
```